# Magento 2.4 Unable to apply data patch: Area code is not set

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, patch-data, data-patch

While executing below data patch with `setup:upgrade` the following error appears in the console.

`Unable to apply data patch Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data\ModuleName for module Vendor_Module. Original exception message: Area code is not set`

I don't understand why this error is raised, I don't see why it has to be set for executing this data patch.

```php
<?php

declare (strict_types = 1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class ModuleName implements DataPatchInterface
{

    /** @var  \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory */
    protected ProductFactory $productFactory;

    /** @var  \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product */
    protected Product $productResourceModel;

    public function __construct(
        ProductFactory $productFactory,
        Product $productResourceModel
    ) {
        $this->productFactory       = $productFactory;
        $this->productResourceModel = $productResourceModel;
    }

    /**
     * @param $productId
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function setVisibility($productId): void
    {
        $product = $this->productFactory->create();
        $this->productResourceModel->load($product, $productId);
        $product->setVisibility(1);
        $this->productResourceModel->save($product);
    }

    /**
     * @param $productId
     * @param $storeId
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function setStoreViewVisibility($productId, $storeId): void
    {
        $product = $this->productFactory->create();
        $this->productResourceModel->load($product, $productId);
        $product->setStoreId($storeId);
        $product->setVisibility(4);
        $this->productResourceModel->save($product);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function apply(): void
    {
            $this->setVisibility(247);
            $this->setStoreViewVisibility(247, 9);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @return array|string[]
     */
    public static function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @return array|string[]
     */
    public function getAliases(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have face same issue into the installData, so i have use this solution and now it's working fine please try this.

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
) {
    ...
    $state->setAreaCode('adminhtml'); // else use 'frontend' or 'globle'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong with this, but my guess is that, from the moment you specify a store `$product->setStoreId($storeId);`, then you are under that store area; which means you need to setup the area code.

Comment: But what area needs to be set then? If you look in \Magento\Framework\App\Area the available options seem a bit odd..

Comment: i would say frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on upgradedata. I was solved it with apply admin area code.

```
protected $_appState;
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState,
        ...
        ...
    ) {
        
        $this->_appState = $appState;
        ...
        ...
    }
```

And I was apply area code to "$this" object

```
              try {
                    $this->_appState->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);

                    or
                    
                    $this->_appState->setAreaCode('admin');


                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->_appState->getAreaCode();
            }            
        }
    }
```